# Matlab angle function to compute phase

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

I am using Matlab's `angle` function to compute the phase of a series of Fourier transforms.  When I use my own `angle` function (below), I get different results.  Can I anyone tell me how the Matlab function is implemented?

```
function a = angle(x)
  a = atan(imag(x)/real(x))
  if (real(x) < 0)
    a = a + pi
  end
```

The result is that the result from Matlab's `angle` function gives a  "better" result.  I'm just wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You should compute phase with [`atan2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html):

```
function a = my_angle(x)
a = atan2(imag(x),real(x));
```

`atan2` computes the four-quadrant inverse tangent. It is more precise than `atan` because the division looses precision. See [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) to learn about how this function is computed.

<strike>I don't know for sure how MATLAB's `angle` is implemented, but it would be weird if it weren't implemented through `atan2`.</strike> [Sardar Usama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5698672/sardar-usama) confirmed in [a comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56603313/matlab-angle-function-to-compute-phase/56604017?noredirect=1#comment99784963_56604017) that this is the way it's implemented in MATLAB, you can type `edit angle` in MATLAB to see the code.

Comment: Use `type angle` or `edit angle` to see. Despite it's the same implementation,  it'd still be better to not name it the same

Comment: @Sardar: I don't have access to MATLAB right now, so I can't `edit angle`. Though it's likely a built-in function, I think you might not see any code anyway. Did you try?

Comment: Yes. They've implemented it the same way that you have shown :)

Comment: @Sardar: With the new storage for real and imaginary components (they're now a single memory block), this is an inefficient implementation as it requires copying the data. I'm disappointed!

Comment: I tested that in R2018a. Can't say for the newer versions.